# Number of topologies on a set

Tags: general-topology, combinatorics

Let $X$ be a nonempty set with $n$ elements. I want to find an upper bound for the number of possible topologies for $X$. I proceed as follows:

The power set $\mathcal P(X)$ contains $2^n$ elements. Since each topology on $X$ is a subset of $\mathcal P(X)$ containing $\emptyset, X$, thus total number of such subsets will be $2^{2^n-2}$. Am I right?

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/8970/number-of-valid-topologies-on-a-finite-set-of-n-elements

Comment: Yes, there are $2^{2^n-2}$ such subsets of $\wp(X)$. Of course, many of them are not topologies, and many of the topologies are homeomorphic.